# IDE for Objective-C and iOS Development other than XCode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ide

Is there an IDE which specifically supports Objective-C and has linked with Cocoa Touch (optionally Cocoa) build tools for easy writing, building and running of programs?

I am looking to switch from XCode because XCode is buggy and crashes when I load files which has thousands of lines of code. Also the beautifier isn't good. It's not that performant.

It doesn't need to come with Interface Builder. I just need to write Objective-C in the IDE. More like Aptana if you have been a web developer.

Comment: If it's just a .m file, I believe textmate supports syntax highlighting? (I may be wrong)  Otherwise, you won't be able to open .xcodeproj files anywhere else other than Xcode.

Comment: .xcodeproj files are not really files than bundles. You can open them like folders. And all meta information is stored as plain text. You can open it with any text editor of your choice.

Comment: Isn't Cocoa and Cocoa Touch compiler is a file that takes input .h & .m files and result into executable?

Comment: @cem Interesting, I've always thought there would be at least certain bits contained as binary.

Comment: @TheAmateurProgrammer: Maybe some data is saved in binary but some spot tests didn't show any. Even set breakpoints are saved as XML. I think, all relevant information is easily accessible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only for writing Obj-C Code, you can use any text editor.

You can not draw any UI like IB, but you can code to construct any of the UI elements.

However I would suggest to use BBEdit.

Or if you wish you can go for any C / C++ / Java IDE. But it wont compile for compiling you need to to switch back to XCode.

Or you can compile through terminal by giving the following command.

```
xcodebuild -project "delta.xcodeproj" -target "delta" -configuration Release OBJROOT="/Users/anoop/desktop/delta" SYMROOT="/Users/anoop/desktop/delta"
```

Comment: So assuming one can compile with this command, why there isn't any IDE which supports Objective-C and runs this command when we may build with the IDE and start iOS simulator when the build was a success?

Comment: There may be or may not be, Or even you can create an IDE that will call this command with your project name and target and all other option!!!  But, why would anyone go for building any thing if it is already there? And Kindly let us know which XCode version are you using and what is your system configuration? And I have worked for few projects having 1000s of classes and had more than half a million errors :) but XCode never failed.

Comment: I would only go the way I mentioned where I found XCode crashing with large files.

Comment: You can also use TextWrangler for large text files. It has syntax highlighting too.

Answer (score 4):

Jetbrains have AppCode http://www.jetbrains.com/objc/. it is an IntelliJ based alternative for Xcode but depends on an installed Xcode for IB and CoreData.

Answer (score 0):

I feel your pain but even if you find an IDE other than XCode you will find yourself coming back to XCode to do something anyway such as the Interface Builder, etc.
Also, unfortunately, AppCode also not perfect. There are scenarios it doesn't cover yet that might hinder you from migrating or cause you to do heavy hacks to get it to work.

However, I have a project with hundreds of files including source files and it works fine for me. I do admit that it crashes from time to time but there is nothing you can do about it. Maybe try refactoring your project to reduce the size of your source files. I did find having large text files can cause it to go bonkers. But it is a good practice anyway to have small class files. Maybe what you are describing is a code smell of bloated classes?

I'm not meaning to offend you or anything. It's just another perspective for you to look at. Use it or don't use it.